# python - imshow not showing any picture

Tags: python, matplotlib, artificial-intelligence, imshow

I have the following code:

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot
import  numpy

data_file = open("train/small_train.csv", "r")
data_list = data_file.readlines()
data_file.close()

all_values = data_list[0].split(",")
image_array = numpy.asfarray(all_values[1:]).reshape((28,28))
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(image_array, cmap="Greys", interpolation="None")
```

this should read the first line of a .csv file and pick the pixel values (`split(","`), put them together to form an image.

The code just runs without any errors but isn't showing the picture...

Comment: Maybe including `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` would help?

Comment: P.S. A general comment is that you should try to come up with a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In layman's terms: anyone should be able to run your example directly. In this case you could have come up with some fictitious data.

Comment: matplotlib.pyplot.show gives moduleError: no module named show

Comment: Did you forget the brackets?

Comment: with brackets it gives syntaxError

Comment: Na @TomdeGeus It shouldn't work without the brackets, but it shouldn't give an error either. Without the bracket, you're just calling the function object, not the function itself. :) To the OP : matplotlib.pyplot.show() should work in my opinion.

Comment: @IMCoins I meant, you should use the brackets ;). To OP: you probably have a syntax error elsewhere.

Comment: I looked at `all_values` and `image_array` but theres no mistake

Comment: it worked fine there is no syntax error..

Comment: Again, PLEASE come up with a minimal WORKING example.... We are here to solve problems, but are not a helpdesk.

Comment: maybe the error is at don't using `%matplotlib inline` but this gives a syntax error...

Comment: what do you mean? thats my full code...

Comment: You can execute your code because you have the `.csv`, but do we have it ?

Comment: The `.csv` is a mnist handwriting training set for ai you can find a smaller version (the version, that i'm using) at `https://github.com/makeyourownneuralnetwork/makeyourownneuralnetwork/blob/master/mnist_dataset/mnist_train_100.csv`

Comment: Got bored and just wrote you what we meant. I also included few python tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, you forgot to use the `show()` method.

You should use `from` keyword to `import` only the function you desire. Doing this, you don't need to call the file in which they are (such as `matplotlib.pyplot`). I also used the `with` keyword that handles very nicely the file director. It opens the file in a clean way, and closes it properly.

```
from  matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import  numpy as np

with open("train/small_train.csv", "r") as data:
    data_list = data.readlines()

all_values = data_list[0].split(",")
image_array = np.asfarray(all_values[1:]).reshape((28,28))
plt.imshow(image_array, cmap="Greys", interpolation="None")
plt.show()
```